# DeleteRow Formula parse error. Google sheets

Tags: worksheet-function, google-sheets

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I want to delete the row if it is True.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The formula shown on the image, `= if K3=true {sheet.deleteRow(i) }`, doesn't follow the Google Sheets formula syntax rules, by the other hand, custom functions can't deleted rows  or do other thing than returning a value / 2D array of values.

Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions